# If function DAX

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I currently have several columns in powerbi:

```
'Dates réelles'[Promesses réelles]
'Dates recalées'[date agrement obtenu recalées]
'Dates recalées'[date signature de os recalées]
'Dates recalées'[date reception operation recalées]
```

and i want to obtain this:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

which is approximately :

- `formule 1` = IF `[Promesse réelles]` > `Today`;  1 ; 0
- `formule 2` =  IF  `formule 1`= 0 and  `date agrément obtenu  recalées` > `Today` ; 1 ; 0
- `formule 3` = IF formule 2 = 0 and  `date signature de os recalées` > `Today` ; 1 ; 0
- `formule 4`    = IF formule 3 = 0 and `date reception opérations recalées` > `Today` ; 1 ; 0

There is a lot of blank cells so i have to considerate it

But i can't figure how to create  my If function

I tried:

```
 formule 1  = 
IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Promesses réelles])>TODAY()),1,0
)
```

but i have some error messages and its not working, i obtain :

" Comparison dax formulas do not support comparing values ​​of type true/false with values ​​of type Date. Use the value or Format function to convert one of the values"

Do you have an idea?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzUZD.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states, by writing `ISBLANK([Promesses réelles])>TODAY()` you're trying to compare the true/false value (`ISBLANK([Promesses réelles]` is an evaluation on its own and will return true or false) with a date value (`TODAY()`).

If you simply want to exclude blanks from your logic you can try this:

```
 IF(
    NOT(ISBLANK([Promesses réelles])),
    IF(
        [Promesses réelles]>TODAY(), 
        1, 
        0
       )
    )
```

If [Promesses réelles] is blank this formula will also return blank, if [Promesses réelles] is not blank and [Promesses réelles] > TODAY(), the formula will return 1. Will return 0 if [Promesses réelles] not blank and [Promesses réelles] <= TODAY().

Comment: Thank you for your answer, function is working but i have 47 "1" which is basically impossible considering i only have datas from 2021 currently which is < to Today.

Any idea about the origin of the problem? I'm not sure if null values have a link with it

Comment: I don't see how this would be related to blank values, what are the [Promesses réelles] dates that have "1"s in the formule 1 column?